# Postgresql Array Functions with QueryDSL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, querydsl

I use the Vlad Mihalcea's library in order to map SQL arrays (Postgresql in my case) to JPA. Then let's imagine I have an Entity, ex.

```
@TypeDefs(
{@TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = 
StringArrayType.class)}
)
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Type(type = "string-array")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text[]")
    private String[] tags;
}
```

The appropriate SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
    tags text[]
);
```

Using QueryDSL I'd like to fetch rows which tags contains all the given ones. The raw SQL could be:

```
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE tags @> '{"someTag","anotherTag"}'::text[];
```

(taken from: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html)

Is it possible to do it with QueryDSL? Something like the code bellow ?

```
predicate.and(entity.tags.eqAll(<whatever>));
```

Comment: I came up with: `predicate.and(booleanTemplate("arraycontains({0}, string_to_array('someTag,anotherTag', ','))", qEntity.tags));` but the functions can't be execute and this exception is thrown: `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 3, column 20 [select blablabla where arraycontains(entity.tags,string_to_array('someTag,anotherTag', ','))]` sources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544332/call-mysql-nested-inner-functions-in-querydsl and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984343/how-to-call-mysql-function-using-querydsl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. 1st step is to generate proper sql: `WHERE tags @> '{"someTag","anotherTag"}'::text[];`
2. 2nd step is described by coladict (thanks a lot!): figure out the functions which are called: @> is arraycontains and ::text[] is string_to_array
3. 3rd step is to call them properly. After hours of debug I figured out that HQL doesn't treat functions as functions unless I added an expression sign (in my case: ...=true), so the final solution looks like this:

   ```
    predicate.and(
            Expressions.booleanTemplate("arraycontains({0}, string_to_array({1}, ',')) = true", 
                    entity.tags,
                    tagsStr)
    );
   ```

where `tagsStr` - is a `String` with values separated by `,`

Comment: Thank you so much for the `=true` part. Saved me hours. One remark: I'd rather use `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.registerFunction(String, SQLFunction)` to register a specific function name for the native jsonb operators. Feels somewhat 'cleaner'.

Answer (score 6):

Since you can't use custom operators, you will have to use their functional equivalents. You can look them up in the psql console with `\doS+`. For `\doS+ @>` we get several results, but this is the one you want:

```
                                          List of operators
   Schema   | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type |      Function       | Description 
------------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------
 pg_catalog | @>   | anyarray      | anyarray       | boolean     | arraycontains       | contains
```

It tells us the function used is called `arraycontains`, so now we look-up that function to see it's parameters using `\df arraycontains`

```
                              List of functions
   Schema   |     Name      | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | arraycontains | boolean          | anyarray, anyarray  | normal
```

From here, we transform the target query you're aiming for into:

```
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE arraycontains(tags, '{"someTag","anotherTag"}'::text[]);
```

You should then be able to use the builder's `function` call to create this condition.

```
ParameterExpression<String[]> tags = cb.parameter(String[].class);
Expression<Boolean> tagcheck = cb.function("Flight_.id", Boolean.class, Entity_.tags, tags);
```

Though I use a different array solution (might publish soon), I believe it should work, unless there are bugs in the underlying implementation.

An alternative to method would be to compile the escaped string format of the array and pass it on as the second parameter. It's easier to print if you don't treat the double-quotes as optional. In that event, you have to replace `String[]` with `String` in the `ParameterExpression` row above

Comment: by `cb` you mean `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder`? I'd like to use only QueryDSL. I used the function you figured out and came with: `predicate.and(booleanTemplate("arraycontains({0},{1})", entity.tags, tags));` where tags is `Expression<String[]>` - "QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 3, column 20 [select blablabla where arraycontains(entity.tags,(?1))]" then

Comment: Well, it's similar enough, and it was the custom operator that is the problem you needed to circumvent. This article should help you create the function call https://luisfpg.blogspot.com/2013/02/the-beauty-of-querydsl-in-sorting.html

Comment: @SerhiiRomanov the correct syntax for the template is `FUNCTION('arraycontains', {0}, {1}) = true`

Answer (score 0):

For **EclipseLink** I created a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_array(array_val text[], string_comma character varying ) RETURNS bool AS $$
        BEGIN
                RETURN arraycontains(array_val, string_to_array(string_comma, ','));
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As pointed out by Serhii, then you can use`Expressions.booleanTemplate("FUNCTION('check_array', {0}, {1}) = true", entity.tags, tagsStr)`