# How to pass String[] as varchar[] through Querydsl to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Trying to solve [Postgresql Array Functions with QueryDSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48280413/476716) more cleanly, I've got this far.

```java
// obj.foo is an ArrayPath<String[], String>
bindings.bind(obj.foo).first((path, value) -> 
        Expressions.booleanTemplate("array_contains({0}, {1}) = true", path, value));
```

this ends up as correct-looking SQL

```sql
where array_contains(obj0_1_.foo, ?)=true
```

but it seems the `String[]` variable is not passed correctly

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function array_contains(character varying[], bytea) does not exist

How can I either (if possible)

1. get the `String[]` value to bind as a `varchar[]`?
2. express the necessary cast in the `booleanTemplate`?

Comment: With some debugging, the bound value is a `StreamWrapper` of what I assume is the Java serialization of the `String[]` - `AC ED 00 05 75 74 00 ...`

Comment: Further, `Arrays.asList(value)` binds as `varchar` for a single item, and `record` for multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `String[]` directly, wrap it in a [`TypedParameterValue`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/TypedParameterValue.html).

The hibernate-types library does [not yet support `varchar[]`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/issues/17), but you can use it to build something that does:

```java
public class VarcharArrayType extends AbstractHibernateType<String[]> {
    public static VarcharArrayType INSTANCE = new VarcharArrayType();

    public VarcharArrayType() {
        super(ArraySqlTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, new TypeDescriptor());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "varchar-array";
    }

    public static class TypeDescriptor extends StringArrayTypeDescriptor {
        @Override
        protected String getSqlArrayType() {
            return "varchar";
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update: in Hibernate 6 this works out of the box. No additional libraries, classes, or settings requires.