# Not converting yearweek function with QueryDSL

Tags: hql, jpql, querydsl, week-number

I would like to use the `yearweek()` function of QueryDSL, which is supported by QueryDSL. This function generates the query `select year(table1.timestamp)*100 + week(table1.timestamp) as col_0_0_ [...]`. This does, however, not return a correct result on year endings. I've already opened a [bug report](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2313) for this issue.

I would rather use the built-in SQL `yearweek()` function, which is directly supported by e.g. MariaDB. Is there a way of using the SQL function `YEARWEEK(timestamp)` with QueryDSL? Or is it possible to use a custom SQL function with QueryDSL, e.g. given as a String?

---

Here is an example on how the two implementations return different results on year endings:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK("2018-01-01");
→ returns 201753, correct

SELECT YEAR("2018-01-01") * 100 + WEEK("2018-01-01")
→ returns 201800, incorrect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the question in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41565647/3233827). You can use a template for this problem.

I used the following template to create a number expression with the SQL yearweek function:

```
Expressions.numberTemplate(Integer.class, "yearweek({0}, 3)", table1.timestamp);
```